# Override Default Jenkins Pipeline Node Block

Tags: jenkins, groovy, kubernetes, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

My company has a small pipeline library that we implicitly load for every build. Is there a way to overload the `node {` block of every build transparently?

My specific case is that I'm provisioning kubernetes slaves with the kubernetes plugin, and I want to provide a default YAML template, while allowing users to pick another template or override specific values. Eg:

```
node {
  // Gets you a Pod with a DinD engine with a low CPU/Mem request/limit
}
```

Optionally overridden by name:

```
node('2-core') {
  // Gets you a Pod with a DinD engine with 2 CPU/ more Mem request/limit
}
```

Or overridden with a template:

```
import com.foo.utils.PodTemplates

slaveTemplates = new PodTemplates()

slaveTemplates.bigPod {
  node {
    // Big node
  }
}
```

Or:

```
def label = "mypod-${UUID.randomUUID().toString()}"
podTemplate(label: label, yaml: """
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  labels:
    some-label: some-label-value
spec:
  containers:
  - name: redis
    image: redis
"""
) {
  node (label) {
    // Same small pod as before PLUS a redis container
  }
}
```

This seems trickiest, since you want the values of the parent to override the values of the child.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this, but, in my opinion, it will lead to confusing behavior and possibly strange error cases.

For example:

`echo.groovy`

```
def call(String string) {
  steps.echo "Calling step echo: $string"
}
```

`Jenkinsfile`

```
echo 'hello'
```

Output:

```
Calling step echo: hello
```

- There is a [blog post here](http://unethicalblogger.com/2017/08/03/overriding-builtin-steps-pipeline.html) that demonstrates this a little more in depth
- Paid support for some pipeline restriction tools are offered by [CloudBees](https://go.cloudbees.com/docs/cloudbees-documentation/cje-user-guide/index.html#pipeline-custom-factories) that might solve your use case

The heaviest way to accomplish this is to of course write a plugin.

Comment: Excellent, thank you! Upvoted. Yes, it's clearly an antipattern, but I'm trying to keep the API simple for my users and so that I don't have to update a gajillion Jenkinsfiles.